# .htaccess rewriting more than it should

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

With help from SO and research I was able to craft a `.htaccess`-file for my Joomla 2.5 site.

Unfortunately, it is rewriting too much and I can't find the expression causing the problem.

**Problem:** `site.com/administrator`, is getting rewritten to `www.site.com`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

## non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]

## old to new
RewriteRule ^index.php/hello$ /hello.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index.php/goodbye$ /goodbye.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^this-is/an-old-link.html$ /this-is-now/a-newer-link.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^galleries/docs/folder_web.pdf$ /printstuff/new-folder.html [L,R=301]    

## old links with parameters
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?p=21(?:&|\s) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /new-stuff/wow-sweetie.html? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?p=99(?:&|\s) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /new-stuff/last-exit.html? [L,R=301]

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F,L]

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

## sitemap
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitemap.xml
RewriteRule .* /index.php?option=com_xmap&view=xml&tmpl=component&id=1&format=html [L]
```

Comment: It looks like your first Cond/Rule will redirect `non-www` to `www`. The `[L]` flag also means this will be the last rule processed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this rule as your first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^administrator(/|$) - [L,NC]
```